# Protocol used by IR LED receiver (50W driver)

Tags: led, serial, infrared

I have a 50W LED driver with a IR remote control that i want to control with a microcontroller.[image: LED driver] I hooked it up to my oscilloscope to try to decipher the data sent between the IR receiver and the remote, but couldn't recognize the protocol used, and the PicoScope software couldn't figure it out either. Any idea what it is? The short 0 pulses are approx. 0.52ms long

[image]

Here is a picture of the receiver :
[image]

Comment: make model? ...........

Comment: the model is unfortunately "generic Ebay", all info about the driver i have is shown in the first image

Comment: RC5 maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RC-5

Comment: That wouldn't explain the long MAB in the beginning of the data

Comment: NEC if the beginning has 9ms pulse and 4.5ms pause.

Comment: www.sbprojects.com/knowledge/ir/ there is a pull down on the top right of the page you can walk through the different protocols, look for the ones that have a sync pattern that starts like taht (some dont have a sync pattern easy to rule out)

Comment: yeah nec would be a place to start.  note there are some that dont follow these standards but are pretty obvious once you have decoded a few of these to figure out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are no lots of protocols used for IR remote controller. Probably RC 5 or NEC.

https://www.vishay.com/docs/80071/dataform.pdf

[image]

If you take apart the remote, you could probably find a chip with markings on it - then you know.

Comment: the pcb on the remote has a big blob of black resin covering the IC, so no luck there

Comment: @Pownyan Hook the IR receiver (if you have some) on arduino and try some NEC libraries to decode.

Answer (score 5):

The "W28" IR remote control for generic Chinese LED lamps uses NEC protocol.

A detailed analysis with Arduino code can be found [here](https://www.instructables.com/id/Reverse-Engineering-RGB-LED-Bulb-with-IR-remote/).